# Как сделать кнопку показать еще на js?

Tags: javascript, json

Использую бд в формате JSON, так вот написал код который выводит товары на страницу в блок с id "masonry", но этот код выводит все записи, как сделать так что бы выводило только 20 а потом просто человек нажимает на кнопку показать еще?

```
 var ul = document.getElementById('masonry');
docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

 //создаем каталог
products.forEach(function(e) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.className = "col-md-2 col-masonry product";
  a.href = 'http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/product/?id=' + e.id;
  //div.style.position = "relative";
  //div.style.marginTop = "20px";
  a.innerHTML = '<div class="product-thumb"><header class="product-header"><img alt="'+ e.name +'" src="' +e.img +'"></header><div class="product-inner"><h5 class="product-title">' + e.name +'</h5><div class="product-desciption">' + e.miniAbout +'</div><div class="product-meta"><span class="product-time"></span><ul class="product-price-list"><li><span class="product-price">'+ e.price +' Грн.</span></li><li><a style="color: #858585" href="http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/sell/?id='+ e.id +'">Продать </a>-<a href="http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/product/?id='+ e.id +'"><span class="product-old-price"> Купить</span></a></li></ul></div><a href="http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/tag/?category='+ e.category +'"><p class="product-location"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> '+ e.category +'</p></a></div></div> ';
  docfrag.appendChild(a);

});

ul.appendChild(docfrag)
```

;

Comment: перед `.forEach` добавляешь счетчик, внутри под условие делаешь `if (cout <= 10) { /*твой код*/} else { /*добавить кнопку*/ }

Comment: Можете дать пример конкретно для этого кода?

Comment: Можете воспользоваться готовыми плагинами,если у Вас возникают большие затруднения. Для этого ищите плагин,примерно по такому запросу lazy load json data

Comment: @arthru http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/GZXbzw?editors=0010 написал с комментариями

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.createElement(...).text is not a function

Comment: @arthru заместо `text` - `innerHTML`. Этот код так то не влияет на суть которую я тебе говорю. Мог бы и сам исправить ошибку)

Comment: Пробовал, тогда пишет shop.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: document.createElement(...).innerHTML is not a function так вот кстати на месте комментов, можешь дописать именно тот код, а то я все равно не совсем понял как его сделать

Comment: @arthru может потому что я пытаюсь создать `btn` а не `button`?))

Comment: @arthru щас напишу...

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, какой смысл бежать по всем в forEach, если надо пробежать только несколько?

Comment: @Grundy я и не хотел бежать по всем элементам, поэтому тут и нужен нормальный метод, который вернет только нужное количество этих элементов

Answer (score 1):

Вот логический пример, как оно должно работать. Есть куча разных реализаций и способов как можно такое сделать.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('masonry');
docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();


var products = [];

function generateProducts (cout) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < cout; i++) {
        newArr.push({
                id: i
            ,   name: 'product' + i
            ,   img: 'img.png'
            ,   miniAbout: 'miniAbout' + i
            ,   price: 100 + (i * 2)
            ,   category: i * 4
        });
    }
    return newArr;
}

products = generateProducts(52);

function getProductsListRange (products, from, to) {
  var template = [];
  var e, a;
  
  if (products.length <= to) { to = products.length;}
  
  for (var i = from; i < to; i++) {
    e = products[i]; // i объект продукта 
    
    a = document.createElement("a");
    a.className = "col-md-2 col-masonry product";
    a.href = 'http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/product/?id=' + e.id;
    
    //div.style.position = "relative";
    //div.style.marginTop = "20px";
    a.innerHTML = '<div><span>'+ e.id +'</span> <span>'+e.name+'</span></div>';
    /*a.innerHTML = '<div class="product-thumb">' +
            '<header class="product-header">' +
                '<img alt="'+ e.name +'" src="' +e.img +'"></header>' +
            '<div class="product-inner">' +
                '<h5 class="product-title">' + e.name +'</h5>' +
                '<div class="product-desciption">' + e.miniAbout +'</div>' +
                '<div class="product-meta">' +
                    '<span class="product-time"></span>' +
                    '<ul class="product-price-list">' +
                        '<li><span class="product-price">'+ e.price +' Грн.</span></li>' +
                        '<li>' +
                            '<a style="color: #858585" href="http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/sell/?id='+ e.id +'">Продать </a>-' +
                            '<a href="http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/product/?id='+ e.id +'">' +
                                '<span class="product-old-price"> Купить</span></a>' +
                        '</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<a href="http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/tag/?category='+ e.category +'">' +
                    '<p class="product-location"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> '+ e.category +'</p>' +
                '</a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';*/
    template.push(a);
    console.log(template);
  }
  
  console.log(template)
  
  if (products.length > to) {
      var btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.innerHTML = 'Показать ещё';
      btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
          productsHTML(getProductsListRange(products, to, to + 10), to, to + 10);
          this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
      });
      template.push(btn);
  }
  
  return template;
}

function productsHTML(list, from, to) {
    var listHtml = list;

    function viewProducts (list) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            docfrag.appendChild(list[i]);
        }
        ul.appendChild(docfrag);
    }
    
    viewProducts(listHtml);
}

productsHTML(getProductsListRange(products, 0, 10), 0, 10);
```

```html
<div id="masonry"></div>
```

Comment: Но я не генерирую продукты я их подключаю с json файла, как сделать что бы все было так как у меня в коде (что бы продукты не генерировались)

Comment: @arthru емае, ты основы знаешь? как можно писать не зная основ. Просто удали мой генератор и подставь свой массив. Я то привел пример, т.к данных у меня нет. Пример рабочий, просто любые данные подставляешь с полями как там заложены и все... А часть твоего кода там закомментирована, просто раскомментируй. Все что тебе нужно удалить все от `var products = [];` до `products = generateProducts(52);` и вставить в свой код

Comment: Да то я уже сам разобрался, только кнопка показать еще не генерируется с низу, вот тут тот пример захостил http://vk.cc/567KXI в разделе каталог товаров

Comment: можно как то переделать ту кнопку поиск товара в кнопку показать еще ?

Comment: дак тебе надо задать начальные данные от 0 до 4, а кнопке стили присвоить которые там, либо вынести кнопку вне обработчика. Чтобы он сам вызывал метод подгрузки и вывода

Comment: @arthru почитай этот пост, https://habrahabr.ru/post/282079/ у тебя слишком лагает страница при скроллинге

Comment: Окей посмотри по коду, попробовал сделать кнопку показать еще но пишет что функция не найдена

Comment: @arthru show.js 49 строка loadbtn нет в dom дереве. У тебя у кнопки нет `id="loadbtn"`

Comment: да но на странице есть <div id="loadbtn"></div>

Comment: @arthru нет, нету. Я проверил

Comment: го по скайпу я вам покажу, возможно так будет гораздо удобнее?

Comment: @arthru у меня нет столько времени

Comment: Пишет "Uncaught ReferenceError: to is not defined"

Comment: @arthru значит её нет, мне она приходит в функцию, ищи ошибку у себя